# Program ends after inputting an integer when it asks 'how old are you'

Tags: python, if-statement

```
print('Hi there, what is your name')
name = input()

if name == 'Alice':
    print('Hello, Alice')
if name != 'Alice':
    print('how old are you?')
    age = int(input())
elif age < 12:
    print('You are not Alice Kiddo.')
elif age > 2000:
    print('Unlike you, Alice is not an undead, immortal vampire.')
elif age > 100:
    print('You are not Alice, Grannie.')
```

When I run the program I get

> Hi there, what is your name
> Jeff
> how old are you?
> 5
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that is you using `elif` instead of `if`. If you use `if` and `elif` combination, it'll always execute in that order and the first caught condition will capture the whole execution.

For example:

```
if name == 'Alice':
    print('how old are you?')
    age = int(input())
elif name == "Alice" and True:
    print("won't be executed")
```

For you to fix it you can either nest the conditions via:

```
if name == "Alice":
    if age == 123:
        do_stuff()
```

which is the same as:

```
if name == "Alice" and age == 123:
    do_stuff()
```

or you can edit your condition tree (if you want to continue the code flow) to `if`s instead and catch each of the cases individually:

```
print('Hi there, what is your name')
name = input()
if name == 'Alice':
    print('Hello, Alice')
if name != 'Alice':
    print('how old are you?')
    age = int(input())

if name == "Alice" and age < 12:
    print('You are not Alice Kiddo.')
if name == "Alice" and age > 2000:
    print('Unlike you, Alice is not an undead, immortal vampire.')
if age > 100:
    print(f'You are not Alice, Grannie, but you might be {name}')
if name == "Bob":
    print("Hi Bob")
```

Comment: Thanks so much Peter for your comprehensive answer! I'm trying to break into back end dev so i'm quite the newbie.

Answer (score 1):

this will work for you

```
print('Hi there, what is your name')
name = input()
if name == 'Alice':
    print('Hello, Alice')
if name != 'Alice':
    print('how old are you?')
    age = int(input())
    if age < 12:
        print('You are not Alice Kiddo.')
    if age > 2000:
        print('Unlike you, Alice is not an undead, immortal vampire.')
    if age > 100:
        print('You are not Alice, Grannie.')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the elif statements, they are used if the if statement is not true

They are like "else if", or "if not, then"

for example:

```
a = input("Enter 1 or 2")
if a == 1:
    print("Why didn't you input two?")
elif a == 2:
    print("Why didn't you input one?")
```